# Need Jquery Datepicker to show "Month" and "Year" as text in dropdown list

Tags: jquery, datepicker

This is what I need. The select menus contain the words "Year" and "Month". (Usually Please Select)

DEMO 1: - [JSFIDDLE1](http://jsfiddle.net/mikeys4u/c8au5/1/)

BUT it should run from the text box as does this demo1.

DEMO 2: - [JSFIDDLE2](http://jsfiddle.net/mikeys4u/u5jmD/)

If I change the LAST LINE in the source code posted

```
<div id="datepicker"></div>
```

to

```
Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker">
```

Then it stops prepending the text to the dropdown?

**SOURCE CODE**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#datepicker').datepicker({

        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,

        onChangeMonthYear: function (year, month) {
            $("#startYear").val(year);
            $("#startMonth").val(month);
        }
    });


$(".ui-datepicker-month").prepend("<option value='' selected='selected'>Month</option>");

$(".ui-datepicker-year").prepend("<option value='' selected='selected'>Year</option>");
});
</script>

<div id="datepicker"></div>
```

Question: - How do I get the second demo to run with a text box and have YEAR and MONTH as does the first demo?

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
$('#startDate').datepicker({
changeMonth: true,
changeYear: true,
dateFormat: 'MM yy',
onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
    var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
    var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
    $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
},
onChangeMonthYear: function (year, month) {
    $("#startYear").val(year);
    $("#startMonth").val(month);
}
});
```

**[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/u5jmD/1/)**

Comment: it does not seem to appear, with YEAR and Month in the first part of the dropdown. (usually this can be PLEASE SELECT)

Comment: I dint get what you want!

Comment: The dropdown MUST have MONTH - JAN - FEB - MAR etc. It must not show JAN on start up... It must show Month on start up as the first fiddle shows......